# Ideal quotient and regular sequences

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $(R,m)$ be a Noetherian local ring. $(x_1,...,x_d)\subset (y_1,...,y_d)$ are two $R$-regular sequences. If we write $x_i=\sum_{j=1}^{d}a_{ij}y_j$, then we have $(x_1,...,x_d):(y_1,...,y_d)=(x_1,...,x_d,a)$ where $a=\operatorname{det}(a_{ij})$(Theorem 2.3.10(a) of Bruns&Herzog's Cohen-Macaulay Rings). It is evident that $(x_1,...,x_d):a\supset (y_1,...,y_d)$. Can we say that $(x_1,...,x_d):a=(y_1,...,y_d)$? If not,  what kind of conditions shall we add?

The question has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4531869/ideal-quotient-and-regular-sequences) with no reply.

Answer (score 1):

If you assume that $R$ is Gorenstein, then by the theory of linkage, it holds in fact more generally for any any unmixed ideal $I$ of depth $d$, that if $J = (x_1,\dots,x_d):I$, then $(x_1,\dots,x_d) : J = I$, cf., i.e., Theorem A.138 of Vasconcelos, *Computational methods of commutative algebra and algebraic geometry*.

I don't know if it holds for more general $R$, provided that $I=(y_1,\dots,y_d)$ is as in your question.

Answer (score 0):

In the graded context, you can, according to Proposition VI.3.1 in the book "Poincar'e Duality Algebras, Macaulay's Dual Systems, and Steenrod Operations" by D. Meyer and L. Smith.